# Link Python script to HTML form

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, contact-form

Ok I have checked some of the related questions and can't seem to find the exact one.

Basically I have pretty much hard-coded a website, there's a tiny bit of use of bootstrap.

I wanted to code a contact form, I've started to learn Python and therefore used Flask to code one.

Right now the form is separate to all of the html files because I coded a separate project.

I know that I could create a full Flask project and redefine all of my html files through the app and have the app generate URL's for it, but that would be a hell of a lot of work at this point for the sake of a contact form.

Is there any way that I can define the form in HTML and have it refer to the Python Flask script?

I have literally no idea how to do this and I can't find an answer anywhere on Google but then I might be searching the wrong thing.

So, here's my HTML:

```
   <form action="routes.py" method="post" class="basic-grey">
         <label>
            <span>Your Name :</span>
             <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" />
         </label>

         <label>
             <span>Your Email :</span>
             <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid Email Address" />
         </label>

         <label>
             <span>Message :</span>
             <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your  Message to Us"></textarea>
         </label>     
          <label>
             <span>&nbsp;</span> 
             <input type="button" class="button" value="Send" /> 
         </label>    
    </form>
```

And here is the Python Flask Script:

```
# Imported the Flask class and a function render_template
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from forms import ContactForm
from flask.ext.mail import Message, Mail
import os

mail = Mail()

# Created an instance/object of the Flask class
app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

# Mapped the URL '/' to the function home().
# Now when someone visits this URL, the function home() will execute.
# This uses a decorator to tell Flask which URL will cause the function below  it to execute.

app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'fernindustrials@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'l3d23pp3l1n'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True

mail.init_app(app)

@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET','POST'])
def contact():
form = ContactForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
        flash('All fields are required.')
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:
        msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='contact@example.com')
        msg.recipients = ["fernindustrials@gmail.com"]
        msg.body="""
        From: %s <%s>
        %s
        """ % (form.name.data, form.email.data,  form.message.data)
        mail.send(msg)

        return render_template('posted.html')

elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

# Use run() to run our app on a local server.
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug = True)
```

In order to not breach the rules I wont post the Forms.py file that I have unless someone needs that to.

Is there anything I need to change or do differently?
Is it even possible?

Also where does the script go in reference to the index.html files, i.e what is the project structure?

Answer (score 0):

The action field in your form tag should be set to an endpoint, not a script. This is unlike PHP, where you do specify the script.

So your form tag may look like:

```
<form action="/contact" method="POST" class="basic-grey">
```